# Visual Studio 2022 Diagnostic tool. How to clear the data

Tags: visual-studio-2022, diagnostic-tools

I am profiling a WinForm application with VS 2022 Diagnostic tools and want to be able to clear diagnostic tool data without restarting the app.
It has a max percentage of disk it can use and I can't increase it because I don't have enough space. When it runns out of the allowed space it stops collecting CPU data and the only way to clear it is to exit VS (it then clears Diagnostic tool data) and then start the app again. That makes it useless because I can't test what I need to test.
Some times even after restart it won't work.

Comment: You can’t. We’ve been complaining about that going back to 2015.

Comment: I think I was able to in 2017